# Example of a group which has $\text{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$ as the automorphism group

Tags: gr.group-theory, automorphism-groups

For the past one week, I have been *trying to learn more* about automorphism groups of different groups. Very recently one of my friend asked this question to me:

- What is the automorphism group of $(\mathbb{Q}^{\ast},\times)$. In short, what is $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}^{\ast})$?

I emailed couple of friends and got the answer as:

- $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}^{\ast})$ is isomorphic to the automorphism group of a free abelian group of countable rank. In particular, it will contain $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ for all $n$.

My question would be :

- > Can we realize $\text{SL}_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$ to be the automorphism group of some group?
- > Are there groups which are which are "*very difficult*" to be realized as the automorphism group of a certain group.

So suppose someone comes and asks me: Is $S_{3}$ or $\text{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ the *automorphism group* of some group, then how can I answer the question? I am particularly interested in seeing how to think for a solution.

Comment: $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}^2$. And $S_3$ is the automorphism group of $C_2\times C_2$ (where $C_2$ is the 2-element group)

Comment: warm-up exercise: show that there is no group having $\mathbb Z$ as automorphism group.

Comment: @a-fortiori: Couldn't think of anything for proving the warm up exercise. An hint would be helpful.

Comment: @Chandrasekhar: As hint: A Popular exercise is to show that if G/Z(G) = Inn(G) is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian. And every abelian group has an automorphism of finite order (which ?). 

Comment: @Ralph: Thanks for the hint. I was thinking that $G/Z \cong \mathscr{I}(G)$ holds only for finite groups. Yes, I know if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian. Are you talking about this map: $x \mapsto x^{-1}$.


Comment: You got it, that's the map. G/Z=Inn(G) holds for every group (cf. Robisnson's group theory book 1.5.3; see also Exercise 1.5(7)). 

Comment: Don't forget that sometimes that automorphism is trivial...

Comment: But if that's trivial then $G$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: A few remarks (about the $\mathrm{SL}_n$ question, say for $n\ge 3$ odd so $H=\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$ has trivial center). Take $G$ with $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\sim H$. Since in $H$ every normal subgroup $\neq 1$ has finite index, $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ is either trivial ($G$ abelian) or has finite index. The first case is excluded ($G$ 2-elementary abelian has finite or uncountable Aut, and $G$ other abelian group has Aut with a central element of order 2, namely inversion). (...)

Comment: (...) So if $G$ has $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\simeq H=\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$, $n\ge 3$ odd, then $\mathrm{Inn}(G)\simeq G/Z(G)$ has finite index in $H$. So an answer should follow from a good understanding of central extensions of normal finite index subgroups  of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$ and their automorphism groups. $n\ge 4$ even is probably similar up to minor details (one should check abelian groups $G$ too). $n=2$ might be very different because it has more finite index subgroups with more automorphisms...

Answer (score 16):

This doesn't quite answer your question, but Bumagin and Wise proved every countable group is the *outer* automorphism group of a finitely generated group.

Comment: And G\"obel and Paras proved in [Automorphisms of metabelian groups with trivial center, Illinois J. Math. 42 (1998), N2, 333-346] that every group is an outer automorphism group of a metabelian group. I believe there are quite a few results of such sort.


Answer (score 6):

Another not quite answer: In the beautiful paper

Automorphism groups of polycyclic by finite groups and arithmetic groups, by Oliver Baues and Fritz Grunewald, 
Publ. Math. IHES 104 (2006), no. 1 ([arXiv version](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511624), [MathReviews](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2264837), [journal version](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10240-006-0003-3))

the authors show that in any cases the automorphism groups of polycyclic-by-finite groups are "arithmetic" (basically subgroups of $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ (results of this sort have actually been know for quite a while for narrower classes of groups -- check the references of the paper).